# Recursive search and replace in text files on Mac and Linux

Tags: linux, macos, shell

In the linux shell, the following command will recursively search and replace all instances of 'this' with 'that' (I don't have a Linux shell in front of me, but it should do).

```
find . -name "*.txt" -print | xargs sed -i 's/this/that/g'
```

What will a similar command on OSX look like?

Comment: Should probably moved to `apple.stackexchange.com` as it's not generic enough for linux nor all devs.

Answer (score 304, accepted):

OS X uses a mix of BSD and GNU tools, so best always check the documentation (although I had it that `less` didn't even conform to the OS X manpage):

https://web.archive.org/web/20170808213955/https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sed.1.html

sed takes the argument after `-i` as the extension for backups. Provide an empty string (`-i ''`) for no backups.

The following should do:

`find . -type f -name '*.txt' -exec sed -i '' s/this/that/g {} +`

The `-type f` is just good practice; sed will complain if you give it a directory or so.

`-exec` is preferred over `xargs`; you needn't bother with `-print0` or anything.

The `{} +` at the end means that `find` will append all results as arguments to one instance of the called command, instead of re-running it for each result. (One exception is when the maximal number of command-line arguments allowed by the OS is breached; in that case `find` will run more than one instance.)

If you get an error like "invalid byte sequence," it might help to force the standard locale by adding `LC_ALL=C` at the start of the command, like so:

`LC_ALL=C find . -type f -name '*.txt' -exec sed -i '' s/this/that/g {} +`

Comment: My "this" in this substitution contains a forward slash (localhost/site) -- I am substituting parts of a URL in an .html file....how do I make such a substitution.  I tried putting in double-quotes, but it fails.

Comment: Sed syntax allows using almost *any* character in place of the slash, e.g. you could use the `%` character: `sed "s%localhost/site%blah/blah%"`.  Another alternative is to backslash-escape the separator: `sed "s/localhost\/site/blah\/blah/"`.

Comment: Thank you let me try that.  I did however try using {} to separate the slash and I still got an error...

Comment: it didn't work after all, I typed the following:  find . -type f -name '*.txt' -exec sed -i '' s%localhost/massignition%www.site.com%/ {} + and I get this error:  sed: 1: "s%localhost/massignitio ...": bad flag in substitute command: '/'

Comment: In your above example you have a `/` too much at the end, after the closing `%`.  And you can't use more than one character as the separator, so if you tried something like `s{}foo{}bar{}` that's not going to work.

Comment: Doesn't work for folders that contain packages or bundles.

Comment: @SteveMoser, I'm not sure what you mean with "doesn't work," but perhaps the problem is that packages and bundles are OS X-specific concepts which are really just directories on the filesystem, and represented to you as if they weren't directories by OS X's Finder application. I believe this works purely through the convention of using the `.app` and `.pkg` extensions for a directory's name, so a script would need to do the same and special-handle directories with such extensions in their names. Otherwise, a directory is just a directory for a Unix script, no matter how it's named.

Comment: @Brynjar I'm guessing that you had some garbled input in your command-line. Make sure there are no invisible characters or anything there. Or maybe it was a displaced backslash, but I don't remember ever getting such an error from sed...

Comment: @TaylanUB Possible to allow for multiple file extensions ? or not specify extension at all ? Tried without specifying the extension but got an error. Thank you

Comment: @YasinYaqoobi `find . -type f \( -name '*.txt' -o -name '*.js' -o ... \) -exec ...` for multiple extensions. Simple leave out the `-name '...'` part for all files.

Comment: Anybody else getting `illegal byte sequence` error? if so, try: `LC_ALL=C find . -type f -name '*.txt' -exec sed -i '' s/this/that/ {} +`, it worked for me.

Comment: This will be replacing only one ocurreny per file, use `/g` for multiple ocurrencies like `LC_ALL=C find . -type f  -exec sed -i '' s/search/replace/g {} + `

Comment: This works for me. But the command runs again through my other script. and replace the 'this' to 'that' one more time. will it be possible how to avoid that?

Comment: will this work on Unix too? Ubuntu? I need something x-platform (something that works on MacOS and *nix)

Comment: @AlexanderMills "Unix" is ambiguous as nearly nobody uses the original Unix nowadays.

Ubuntu is based on Debian which in turn is a GNU-based operating system (like most "Linux distros"), and the code will work on GNU.

Comment: I had to make one change to this in order to get it to work -- I needed to add quotes around the sed find/replace as well as add the g modifier so my command ended up being `LC_ALL=C find . -type f -name '*.txt' -exec sed -i '' "s/this/that/g" {} +`

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on Ubuntu/Debian Linux.

Comment: @jmort253 it definitely should work on Debian and Ubuntu. What problem does it cause in your case?

Comment: @TaylanKammer Here is what I get in Debian: `echo "this is good" > test.txt && find . -type f -name '*.txt' -exec sed -i '' s/this/that/g {} +` and output: 
`sed: can't read s/this/that/g: No such file or directory`.  I think Debian is getting tripped up by the two single quotes and then treating the pattern as the filename.  What Linux distro do you use?

Comment: I confirmed it's the same result on both Debian and Ubuntu.  Maybe the sed tool between GNU Linux and BSD have diverged in the past several years?

Comment: @jmort253 You're totally right, I had forgotten that this answer is MacOS-specific and thought that GNU sed's "-i" switch works exactly the same as the BSD one because it does basically the same thing. Comes out that there's a very annoying difference, which is that there must be *no* whitespace between the "-i" and the file extension. (So when there's no file extension it's just a plain "-i".) https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Command_002dLine-Options

Comment: @TaylanKammer thanks for confirming I'm not crazy. Cheers. :). Too bad they didn't base macOS on Linux instead of BSD. I wonder if that would have made things easier.

Answer (score 237):

For the mac, a more similar approach would be this:

```
find . -name '*.txt' -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i "" "s/form/forms/g"
```

Comment: I wish I could upvote this every time I come back to it and use it. It'd be at +15 by now, easy.

Comment: For some reason, it does not work for me. It does nothing. I'm inside the folder form360 and I´m trying to change all string instances with the name easyform to form360, I´m running the following command: `find . -name '*.php' -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i "" "s/easyform/form360/g"`

Comment: for me, this should be correct answer. It's the only one that worked for me.

Comment: -print0 | xargs -0 does not work on my mac when file name contains space.

Comment: sed: .: in-place editing only works for regular files

Comment: Upvoted. Rly solved my problem with renaming production database dumps :)

Answer (score 26):

As an alternative solution, I'm using this one on Mac OSX 10.7.5

```
grep -ilr 'old-word' * | xargs -I@ sed -i '' 's/old-word/new-word/g' @
```

Credit goes to: [Todd Cesere's answer](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-replace-string-words-in-many-files/)

Comment: This one works well! Other scripts adds an extra end of line in some cases on OSX! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Downside of using grep with `*` is that it will be much more slower. Consider `-I` to avoid binary files, use `--exclude-dir` or a pattern like `{dir1,dir2}`

Comment: does NOT work `$ grep -ilr 'fastapi' * | xargs -I@ sed -i '' 's/fastapi/flask/g' @` and output is 
`sed: RE error: illegal byte sequence
sed: RE error: illegal byte sequence
sed: RE error: illegal byte sequence
sed: RE error: illegal byte sequence
sed: RE error: illegal byte sequence
sed: RE error: illegal byte sequence
sed: RE error: illegal byte sequence`

Comment: @uberrebu It worked, but you are including a parameter to remove a trailing newline and one or all of your directories include binary files. Fortunately for you, `sed` fails, instead of corrupting the files. Large-scale destructive commands are best run in folders with some method of version control (ie. git) to prevent irreversible damage.

Answer (score 20):

None of the above work on OSX.

Do the following:

```
perl -pi -w -e 's/SEARCH_FOR/REPLACE_WITH/g;' *.txt
```

Comment: how to scape '/' if SEARCH_FOR and REPLACE_WITH are paths?

Comment: Use a different delimiter. If you're using paths, a colon or pipe would work. 's|SEARCH|REPLACE|g', for example. Our use braces, as in 's{SEARCH}{REPLACE}'.

Comment: dito question, trying it no on Mac -- but it seems to generate an error?  For example, my path gets interpreted as a file? -bash: localhost/nohost: No such file or directory

Comment: this does not recurse through folders deep. Only one level.

Comment: For more info about this command read this https://lifehacker.com/5810026/quickly-find-and-replace-text-across-multiple-documents-via-the-command-line

Comment: Both the `grep` and `find` answers worked perfectly on Mac (and were far more efficient).

Comment: it searches in current directory only. How to search files in subdirectories?

Answer (score 14):

If you are using a zsh terminal you're able to use wildcard magic:

`sed -i "" "s/search/high-replace/g" *.txt`

Comment: As OSX now has ZSH terminals by default, this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Tried all the above answers but none worked, except this one, on Macbook Air M1 2021. Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

A version that works on both Linux and Mac OS X (by adding the `-e` switch to `sed`):

```
export LC_CTYPE=C LANG=C
find . -name '*.txt' -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i -e 's/this/that/g'
```

Comment: I had to do the export from this answer + the line from the accepted answer (I didn't want backup files to be generated)

Comment: to adress the 'illegal byte sequence' error, try setting the LOCALE before running the command:

`export LC_CTYPE=C && export LANG=C`

Comment: DO NOT EVER RUN this with '\*' instead of '\*.filetype' as I did if you are using Git. Or you can say goodbye to all your unpublished work.

Comment: The mac version of the sed command requires an '' after the -i, so this answer is incorrect

Answer (score 6):

This is my workable one. on mac OS X 10.10.4

```
grep -e 'this' -rl . | xargs sed -i '' 's/this/that/g'
```

The above ones use *find* will change the files that do not contain the search text (add a new line at the file end), which is verbose.

Comment: does NOT work `$ grep -e 'fastapi' -rl . | xargs sed -i '' 's/fastapi/flask/g'` and here is output
`sed: RE error: illegal byte sequence`

Answer (score 6):

**2021**

What worked for me :

```
LC_ALL=C && LANG=C && find . -type f | xargs sed -i '' 's/old/new/g'
```

Comment: It worked for me without the `LC_ALL=C && LANG=C &&` part. Why do you need that?

Comment: You'll get a byte sequence error about ASCII to UTF conversion otherwise (likely depending on what characters you're using)

Answer (score 3):

Whenever I type this command I always seem to hose it up, or forget a flag. I created a Gist on github based off of TaylanUB's answer that does a global find replace from the current directory. This is Mac OSX specific.

https://gist.github.com/nateflink/9056302

It's nice because now I just pop open a terminal then copy in:

curl -s https://gist.github.com/nateflink/9056302/raw/findreplaceosx.sh | bash -s "find-a-url.com" "replace-a-url.com"

You can get some weird byte sequence errors, so here is the full code:

```
#!/bin/bash
#By Nate Flink

#Invoke on the terminal like this
#curl -s https://gist.github.com/nateflink/9056302/raw/findreplaceosx.sh | bash -s "find-a-url.com" "replace-a-url.com"

if [ -z "$1" ] || [ -z "$2" ]; then
  echo "Usage: ./$0 [find string] [replace string]"
  exit 1
fi

FIND=$1
REPLACE=$2

#needed for byte sequence error in ascii to utf conversion on OSX
export LC_CTYPE=C;
export LANG=C;

#sed -i "" is needed by the osx version of sed (instead of sed -i)
find . -type f -exec sed -i "" "s|${FIND}|${REPLACE}|g" {} +
exit 0
```

Answer (score 1):

I used this format - but...I found I had to run it three or more times to get it to actually change every instance which I found extremely strange.  Running it once would change some in each file but not all. Running exactly the same string two-four times would catch all instances.

```
find . -type f -name '*.txt' -exec sed -i '' s/thistext/newtext/ {} +
```

Comment: You needed to run this command multiple times b/c your sed regex needs a `g` at the end, otherwise it only replaces the first occurrence of `thistext` in a line. So your regex should be `s/thistext/newtext/g`

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me on mac

```
LC_ALL=C && LANG=C && find . -type f | xargs sed -i '' 's/OLD_STRING/NEW_STRING/g'
```

however it was much faster with specifying the file types I needed to search/replace in

```
LC_ALL=C && LANG=C && find . -type f -name '*.html' | xargs sed -i '' 's/OLD_STRING/NEW_STRING/g'
```

and as I was search/replacing urls, had to put backslash (`\`) before slashes

```
LC_ALL=C && LANG=C && find . -type f -name '*.html' | xargs sed -i '' 's/https:\/\/yahoo.com/https:\/\/google.com/g'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -type f | xargs sed -i '' 's/string1/string2/g'
```

Refer [here](https://coderwall.com/p/n-sxiq/replace-a-string-recursively-in-a-directory-on-mac-os-x) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

### For *both* macOS and Linux:

I'm not sure that the other answers address *both* Linux and macOS. If there are some that do, perhaps we can edit them to make that point clear.

Below is what I used in order to target *both* platforms.

Assume the file we want to perform the find/replace on contains the following text:

**file.txt:**

```
{{FROM}} hello world
```

Here is the script, **replace.bash:**

```
    #!/bin/bash
    PATTERN="s/{{FROM}}/HELLOWORLD/"
    if [[ `uname -s`" == "Darwin" ]]; then
        sed -i '' "$PATTERN" file.txt
        echo Darwin
    else
        sed -i "$PATTERN" file.txt
        echo Linuxxxx
    fi
```

I later discovered that using single brackets and a single equals cooperated better between sh and bash:

**replace.sh:**

```
    PATTERN="s/{{FROM}}/HELLOWORLD/"
    if [ `uname -s` = "Darwin" ]; then
        sed -i '' "$PATTERN" file.txt
        echo Darwin
    else
        sed -i "$PATTERN" file.txt
        echo Linuxxxx
    fi
```

#### Your own cross-platform sed:

I can see how someone might replace $PATTERN with $1 and file.txt with $2 and actually be able to create a wrapper around sed that works on both platforms, such as:

**ssed**:

```
    PATTERN="$1"
    FILE=$2
    if [ `uname -s` = "Darwin" ]; then
        sed -i '' "$PATTERN" $FILE
    else
        sed -i "$PATTERN" $FILE
    fi
```

```
$ chmod 755 ssed
$ ./ssed 's/{{FROM}}/jameswashere/' file
```

The file would then contain:

```
jameswashere hello world
```

#### What about recursive find/replace?

Now that we have our own platform-independent sed wrapper, we can use it, along with find, to loop through subdirectories and perform the find/replace on matching files:

```
$ find . -name "file" -exec ./ssed 's/{{FROM}}/that/g' {} \;
```

Answer (score -1):

https://bitbucket.org/masonicboom/serp is a go utility (i.e. cross-platform), tested on OSX, that does recursive search-and-replace for text in files within a given directory, and confirms each replacement. It's new, so might be buggy.

Usage looks like:

```
$ ls test
a  d  d2 z
$ cat test/z
hi
$ ./serp --root test --search hi --replace bye --pattern "*"                         
test/z: replace hi with bye? (y/[n]) y
$ cat test/z
bye
```