# Replace all instances of a certain phrase with user defined macOS

Tags: macos, terminal, grep

I have a collection of different static .html files. I want to recursively look through all .html files in the current folder and:

replace all instances of image.jpg with a user string.

replace all instances of textBlock1 with another user string.

replace all instances of textBlock2 with a third user string.

where image.jpg/ textBlock1/ textBlock2 are the only ones looked for exactly as written e.g. not tExtblock1

How do I accomplish this using terminal? Must work on a fresh macOS install.

Previous answers do not use user input See: [Recursive search and replace in text files on Mac and Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9704020/recursive-search-and-replace-in-text-files-on-mac-and-linux)

Comment: What does your last sentence mean? That the only problem remaining is getting the user input? Or that you don't need user input to do the replacement?

Comment: What does your second sentence mean? Are the three pieces of text related to the phrase? Or entirely independent? So could the phrase be *"Scary Stories"* and only if a file contains that phrase, you want to replace the text `Vampire 1` with `Zombie 1` and likewise for two other texts?

Comment: Added information my good man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This little `bash` script should do as you wish. Save it as `modhtml` and make it executable, just necessary one time, with:

```
chmod +x modhtml
```

and then you can run it with:

```
./modhtml
```

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -n "Enter string1: "
read str1
echo -n "Enter string2: "
read str2
echo -n "Enter string3: "
read str3
echo DEBUG: str1=$str1
echo DEBUG: str2=$str2
echo DEBUG: str3=$str3
# Find all files (not directories), in the current directory and below...
# ... called "*.html" and, for each one, execute "sed" to change...
# ... image.jpg to str1
# ... textBlock1 to str2
# ... textBlock2 to str3
find . -type f -name \*.html -print -exec sed -e "s/image.jpg/$str1/g" -e "s/textBlock1/$str2/g" -e "s/textBlock2/$str3/g" {} \;
```

As it stands, it tells you the names of the files it would change and how they will look afterwards but doesn't actually change anything.

If it looks good - make a copy of your files first then run it for real by changing the last line to:

```
find . -type f -name \*.html -exec sed -i.bak -e "s/image.jpg/$str1/g" -e "s/textBlock1/$str2/g" -e "s/textBlock2/$str3/g" {} \;
```

If you want the user to be prompted for the string via a GUI-style prompt, rather than in the Terminal, replace the first few lines like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
str1=$(osascript -e 'Tell application "System Events" to display dialog "Enter string1:" default answer ""' -e 'text returned of result' 2>/dev/null)
str2=$(osascript -e 'Tell application "System Events" to display dialog "Enter string2:" default answer ""' -e 'text returned of result' 2>/dev/null)
str3=$(osascript -e 'Tell application "System Events" to display dialog "Enter string3:" default answer ""' -e 'text returned of result' 2>/dev/null)
echo DEBUG: str1=$str1
echo DEBUG: str2=$str2
echo DEBUG: str3=$str3
```

It will look like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Mark. You went above and beyond with this in depth answer. Top man