# Why does (macOS) grep seem to be waiting for stdin when searching recursively?

Tags: macos, grep

I'm trying to do a quick bulk search and replace for some common strings across a large number of source files.  I'm doing this on a Mac, so I know it sometimes behaves a little differently.  To start, I'm trying to get the list of all files recursively that contain the string I want to change:

`grep -rlF 'oldtext' .`

When the command runs, it appears to wait for stdin after displaying a list of files that contain the string I'm looking for.  Control doesn't return to a prompt, and I can type and press enter with no real reaction from the terminal aside from the terminal showing what I type as I type it.

Am I calling `grep` incorrectly, or is there something about it running on a Mac that I'm not accounting for?

Comment: See if answers in this post help - https://stackoverflow.com/q/9704020/5291015

Comment: Use `grep` to **g/re/p** within files and use `find` to **find** files. Don't use `grep` to **find** files - there is a big clue in the names of the tools what they are best used for. You're also playing with fire using `grep` to find `oldtext` as a string (`-F`) but then using `sed` to replace `oldtext` as a regexp - that can easily produce unexpected/undesirable results. If you [edit] your question to provide concise, testable sample input and expected output then we can help you do whatever it is you're trying to do the right way.

Comment: or try using an explicit placeholder for `xargs` like `xargs -I {} sed -i ''  's/oldtext/newtext/g' {}`

Comment: How do you know it's polling on stdin? When you type `oldtext` does it echo that back?

Comment: I simplified and removed some of the wider context since it was pulling in discussion that wasn't quite related to the issue I was trying to ask about.  Though, it seems the actual issue was that I wasn't being patient enough while the command was running across the large number of files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading [oguz ismail's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62310068/why-does-macos-grep-seem-to-be-waiting-for-stdin-when-searching-recursively#comment110201821_62310068), I tried a few other things and realized that the command *was not* waiting for stdin.  Instead, it was still running without finding any further results for nearly a minute.  After this significant delay, further files were listed as more files were found.  After a few other similar delays, the command completed as I was originally expecting.

There were just so many source files that I thought it was waiting for stdin because the MacOS terminal allows you to continue to type while commands are running.

Comment: Check out [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep) if you wish to speed up search, especially if you have multiple cores and you wish to avoid searching files in gitignore, etc

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want to replace a string in a file but not update the timestamp, etc. of files that don't contain that string. I'd do that as something like this if neither text can contain backslashes

```
tmp=$(mktemp) || exit
while IFS= read -r file; do
    awk -v old='oldtext' new='newtext' '
        s=index($0,old) { $0=substr($0,s-1) new substr($0,s+length(old)); f=1 }
        { print }
        END { exit !f }
    ' "$file" > "$tmp" &&
    mv "$tmp" "$file"
done < <(find . -type f)
```

That will work with POSIX tools as long as your file names don't contain newlines.

If your old or new text can contain a backslash it'd require a small tweak to set the awk variables from `ENVIRON[]` or `ARGV[]` instead of with `-v` (see [How do I use shell variables in an awk script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script)).

The above is doing string operations, which sed doesn't support. See [Is it possible to escape regex metacharacters reliably with sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613304/is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed) for what you'd have to do to get sed to act as if it were using strings.